# Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN disconnects intermittently in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, wifi-driver

Since I have migrated from Windows 7 to Windows 8, my WiFi connection has been a nightmare.

The disconnection occurs a lot of times, intermittently.

I am going to contact Intel since I think Microsoft will not provide any useful information. The latest contact I had with their support about ATI Radeon's driver bug was pretty bad.

I am sharing my info, regarding my Wifi network adapter, and maybe someone can give me some tips to solve this connectivity issue:

**Device:** 
Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN

**Location:** 
PCI bus 4, device 0, function 0

**Advanced Properties:**
802.11n Channel Width for band 2.4: 20Mhz Only
802.11n Channel Width for band 5.2: Auto
802.11n Mode: Enabled
Ad Hoc Channel 802.11b/g: 1
Ad Hoc QoS Mode: WMM Disabled
Fat Channel Intolerant: Disabled
Mixed Mode Protection: CTS-to-self Enabled
Preferred Band: 1. No Preference
Roaming Aggressiveness: 3. Medium
Transmit Power: 5. Highest
Wireless Mode: 6.802.11a/b/g

**Driver info:**
Provider: Intel
Driver date: 1/22/2012
Driver version: 14.3.2.1
Digital Signer: Microsoft Windows Hardware Compatibility Publisher
Driver files: C:\windows\system32\Drivers\NETwNs64.sys
C:\windows\system32\Drivers\vwifibus.sys
C:\windows\system32\NETwNc64.dll
C:\windows\system32\NETwNr64.dll

**Power management info:**
Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power

**Connection info:**
Security type: WPA2-Personal
Encryption type: TKIP

The router is Dlink DIR-300. Without any configuration changes since Windows 7, now I am using Windows 8, so it seems there is something weird with operating system or Intel Wifi driver.

In [Intel Driver Update utility page](http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect#), it says:

> Product Detected: Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN
>
> Current Driver Installed: 15.1.1.0
>
> This device is unknown or unsupported. Please contact the manufacturer
>   for possible updates. [More information>>](http://www.intel.com/support/iduufaq.htm)

Here is the Intel's support link: https://supportmail.intel.com/scripts-emf/welcome.aspx?id=1783

Comment: Have there been any changes around nearby WiFi devices?  Other APs suddenly online or on the same channel?  Do multiple site surveys and see if anything appears. Possibly unrelated to the upgrade to WIN8

Comment: No changes so far. My wife's notebook is still using Windows 7 and her Wifi connectivity is fine. Mine is unstable since the OS change :-(